# What's the difference between blockchain and immutable linked list?

Tags: algorithm, immutability, blockchain, merkle-tree

There is an interview question: What's the difference between blockchain and immutable linked list?

I answered they were the same technology and then failed the test. Please correct me what I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each item in a linked list usually points to the next item in the list with a pointer or memory address.

Each block in a block chain usually references the previous block via it's hash.

Saying a linked list is immutable would be relative to how immutable it actually is. Is it encrypted? It can still be changed to something else, that doesn't make it immutable in a distributed environment. A blockchain is made immutable (relatively, not absolutely) by the total work (proof of work) that has been done on the chain and the network consensus to accept the longest chain. More than a majority of hashpower on the network could theoretically mutate the chain and still be following consensus rules (51% attack).